# Differences between :init-state vs :state at build function

Tags: clojurescript, om

I understand that you can initiate the state of a component by passing a map as the value of the :init-state keyword. But by passing this map as the value of the :state keyword, for example, between a component and its child component, now they can share that same state? Is that it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is when the childs state gets set.

- `:init-state` is only set once, when the component is mounted.
- `:state` is set on each render.

Therefore, `:init-state` should be used to (as the name suggests), initialise the state. On the other hand, `:state` is used to set state that changes over time.

Comment: Bit late, I know, especially with Om Next and all, but I should probably have said that :state is used for a parent to control the child's state (not to change state on a particular trigger. `om/set-state!` can be used for that purpose)